# Uncaught ReferenceError: showResults is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I keypress in the input console is continuously showing the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showResults is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

As you can see in the code, the function is defined. When I remove the AJAX code it starts working. I am unable to find out what the problem is.

```js
let search = $("#livesearch")

function showResults(str) {
  if (str.length === 0) {
    search.addClass("hide");
  } else {
    search.removeClass("hide");
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "/search";
    contentType: "application/json",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      query: str
    }),
    success: function(result) {
      search.html(result.response);
    }
  })
}
```

```css
#addbtn {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(237, 245, 229);
}

#livesearch {
  background-color: #dddd;
  position: absolute;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

a:link,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 ">
  <label class="form-label">Add Users</label>
  <input id="userinput" type="text" name="users[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" onkeyup="showResults(this.value)">
  <div id="livesearch" class="p-3 col-12 hide">This</div>
  <button id="addbtn" class="form-control mt-3" type="button" onClick="addInput();">Add</button>
  <div id="error" class="text-danger p-2"></div>
  <div id="formulario" class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap mt-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have issues in JS, always open devtools and check the console for errors. The problem in this case is because you have a `;` in the wring place - after `url: "/search";`. This means the function is not defined correctly and cannot be called. Change the `;` to a `,` and the code works.

As an aside to the problem, don't use the `onX` event attributes in your HTML. They are massively outdated and no longer good practice. Bind unobtrusive event handlers using jQuery's `on()` method or the plain JS `addEventListener()`

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $search = $("#livesearch")

  $('#userinput').on('input', e => {
    let str = e.target.value;
    $search.toggleClass('hide', !str.length);

    $.ajax({
      url: "/search",
      contentType: "application/json",
      method: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        query: str
      }),
      success: function(result) {
        search.html(result.response);
      }
    })
  });

  $('#addbtn').on('click', e => {
    console.log('add...');
  });
});
```

```css
#addbtn {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(237, 245, 229);
}

#livesearch {
  background-color: #dddd;
  position: absolute;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

a:link,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 ">
  <label class="form-label">Add Users</label>
  <input id="userinput" type="text" name="users[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
  <div id="livesearch" class="p-3 col-12 hide">This</div>
  <button id="addbtn" class="form-control mt-3" type="button">Add</button>
  <div id="error" class="text-danger p-2"></div>
  <div id="formulario" class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap mt-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I was able to get things work out